# Dispatch Main Queue - right way to do it?

Tags: swift, dispatch

I am not sure how I should use the `DispatchQueue.main.async` from a background thread. Should I use it only for the UI code, or for everything?

Which one is more energy efficient?

**Example:**

**For UI only**

```
worldMessagesFunctions.delete(wmId: cell.worldMessageId) { response in

    if let response = response {
        if response!.type == 1 {

            // Remove value from the source array of the tableView
            if let index = WorldMessagesStore.shared.worldMessages.index(where: { $0.id! == cell.worldMessageId }) {
                WorldMessagesStore.shared.worldMessages.remove(at: index)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                    self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
                    self.tableView.endUpdates()
                }                    
            }                
            print("Okay")                
        } else {                
            print("Error")                
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            activityIndicator.removeFromSuperview()
        }            
    }
}
```

**Or For the whole after the response is recieved from the background thread**

```
worldMessagesFunctions.delete(wmId: cell.worldMessageId) { response in

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        if let response = response {
            if response!.type == 1 {

                // Remove value from the source array of the tableView
                if let index = WorldMessagesStore.shared.worldMessages.index(where: { $0.id! == cell.worldMessageId }) {
                    WorldMessagesStore.shared.worldMessages.remove(at: index)

                    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                    self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
                    self.tableView.endUpdates()
                }                
                print("Okay")                
            } else {                
                print("Error")                
            }
            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            activityIndicator.removeFromSuperview()
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: for me second option is better as soon as api complete transfer everything in main queue and perform table operations quickly

Answer (score 4):

The second one is better. The first way, things can happen in the wrong order, and you are sharing WorldMessagesStore across threads.

Comment: Exactly !! That was big doubt i had !!

Comment: The better solution is to do the potentially long running parsing and updating on a separate serial queue and use that separate queue for all interactions with the datastore.  That way you'e protected from multithread access and ordering issues.  But, "better" and "best" are why this is a "primarily opinion" question :)